# Basic form PHP Help - Want parameters to be passed to a different URL

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I want the parameters in my HTML form to be added to a different website, not mine when the user clicks submit. I want them to go to the results on that page. Please tell me how to do this. Right now I have the below code, but it just adds the parameters to the page that it's on on submit.

```
<form name="find-homes">

Min Price: <input type="text" name="lp">
Max Price: <input type="text" name="hp">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" method="POST" action="http://wwww.different-website-not-mine.com">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I owe an apology, as my former answer was incorrect (it applies to javascript-based POSTs, not regular HTML-based)
You can accomplish this with the "action" attribute when submitting, and can specify a full domain name.

```
<form name="find-homes" method="post" action="http://www.other-website.com/"
```

OLD RESPONSE (wall of shame):

Unfortunately, this is explicitly made not possible by all commonly-used browsers. Wikipedia calls it [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Example of the risk involved: Let's say someone were on a malicious website, while logged into Amazon.com with a cookie. The malicious site has someone fill out a form, with hidden fields telling the browser to buy the website owner chocolate chip cookies. Then, the form is submitted to Amazon's buy page. Theoretically, without really knowing it, the user just bought their attacker cookies. That's a very quick-and-dirty definition of it, but sadly you can't do exactly what you're looking to do.

If you want to post a more generalized version of your problem, it's possible we could offer another solution.

EDIT: For clarity, I will note there are some complex solutions available, but they depend on you having deep-level control of the other domain. I kind of assumed at first that you were posting to someone else's website, so I didn't bother going into detail.

Comment: It's a real estate website I do have a little control over the other domain. My website becomes a sub directory of the 2nd website on the results page. So I want it to go to www.mywebsite.resultswebsite.com

Comment: @Mike please see updated answer; my apologies for the misinformation.